# behavior of scalar product defined by trace under commutator

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Define
$$\langle X,Y \rangle := \operatorname{tr}XY^t,$$
where $X,Y$ are square matrices with real entries and $t$ denotes transpose.

I have some troubles in proving that
$$ \langle [X,Y],Z \rangle = - \langle Y,[X,Z] \rangle,$$
where square brackets denote commutator.

Let me update my **questin** to **part ii**. You have proven that my commutation relation without a transpose is wrong, while it is correct if we put a $t.$

Then I'd say I'm in trouble, because the next step would be to define
$$\operatorname{ad}_XY:=[X,Y]$$ and claim that by the above (false) property we have that $\operatorname{ad}$ is antisymmetric, i.e.
$$\langle \operatorname{ad}_XY,Z\rangle =- \langle Y,\operatorname{ad}_XZ\rangle:$$
Do you know of a way to recover such a nice property or something similar?

Comment: Is $[X,Y]=XY-YX$?

Comment: The statement is not true. Are you sure you have jotted down the statement word to word?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\langle Y,[X,Z^t] \rangle$ on the RHS?

Comment: the commutator is what you write above; this statement appears in my notes, and I believed it to be false too; with a transposed does it become true? also, can you find a counterexample to the case without transpose?

Answer (score 2):

$$\langle XY-YX,Z\rangle=\langle XY,Z\rangle-\langle YX,Z\rangle\\=\langle Y,X^tZ\rangle-\langle Y,ZX^t\rangle\\=\langle Y,[X^t,Z]\rangle$$
**Counterexample for the OP's equation:** Let $X=Z=\left[\array{0 & 1\\0 &0}\right]$ and $Y=\left[\array{1&0\\0&2}\right]$. We have $XZ-ZX=0\implies \langle Y,[X,Z]\rangle=0$, whereas $$X^tZ-ZX^t=\left[\array{-1&0\\0&1}\right]\implies\langle Y,[X^t,Z]\rangle=1.$$

Comment: very well, then I am in trouble (see above ;)

Comment: @Nicolo' Aren't the matrices you work with symmetric?

Comment: it is just said they are $n \times n$ real matrices: is there a way to make sense of $\operatorname{ad}$ above without requiring symmetric matrices?

Comment: Is this ad any different from the commutator you had before? What's its significance? I cannot see the equation works as is without any assumption on $X$ or $Z$.

Comment: it is precisely defined as commutator, that's why I think I'm missing something; I think the name ad comes from an Ad at the level of Lie algebra, where it is defined in similar way

Answer (score 1):

The key properties to use are

$$\langle A,B\rangle=\langle B, A\rangle,$$

i.e. with $tr((AB)^t)=tr(AB),$ and

$$tr(ABC^t)=tr(BC^tA),$$

for all $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Still I don't see how to use them to reconstruct the combination above, maybe I'm a little dumb

Comment: Sorry for the long time to answer, pc issues. Please have a look at @S.B. answer: in the second equality he uses the property of the trace I wrote in my answer (the second one).